# iCal4j updating and deleting VEvents in iCalendar

Tags: java, icalendar, ical4j

I am making an application that creates multiple VEvents and it also needs to be able to update and cancel. Everywhere where I searched for this information, no one actually showed any code with Java, just explained in words what need to be done. So I did what I think should be right. And below is what I got. First I created VEvents and than I tried to delete them, but when I opened ics file the calendar still showed those VEvents. What do you think is wrong? And how can I accomplish what I need? Also my application is not concerned with sending invitation or something like that, those events should only be showed in the calendar who opens the file.

```
BEGIN:VCALENDAR
PRODID:-//Ben Fortuna//iCal4j 1.0//EN
VERSION:2.0
CALSCALE:GREGORIAN
BEGIN:VEVENT
DTSTAMP:20140327T221422Z
DTSTART:20140402T060000
DURATION:PT1H
SUMMARY:jTextField2
SEQUENCE:0
DESCRIPTION:description
UID:jTextField21
END:VEVENT
BEGIN:VEVENT
DTSTAMP:20140327T221422Z
DTSTART:20140403T060000
DURATION:PT1H
SUMMARY:jTextField2
SEQUENCE:0
DESCRIPTION:description
UID:jTextField22
END:VEVENT
BEGIN:VEVENT
DTSTAMP:20140327T221422Z
DTSTART:20140404T060000
DURATION:PT1H
SUMMARY:jTextField2
SEQUENCE:0
DESCRIPTION:description
UID:jTextField23
END:VEVENT
BEGIN:VEVENT
DTSTAMP:20140327T221422Z
UID:jTextField21
STATUS:CANCELLED
SEQUENCE:1
END:VEVENT
BEGIN:VEVENT
DTSTAMP:20140327T221422Z
UID:jTextField22
STATUS:CANCELLED
SEQUENCE:1
END:VEVENT
BEGIN:VEVENT
DTSTAMP:20140327T221422Z
UID:jTextField23
STATUS:CANCELLED
SEQUENCE:1
END:VEVENT
END:VCALENDAR
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How is this icalendar stream going to be propagated to the clients ?

If it is just an ics file stored on some web server that calendar client subscribe to using HTTP GET, then clients will typically poll for changes in the file. Events which are no longer part of that stream will implicitly disappear.

If the iCalendar stream is going to be used by clients in some other way (e.g. via email), please specify how.

In any case, having a single stream with the same event (same UID) multiple times in different state is not the way to propagate changes.

Comment: The ics file that I will create will be imported to iCal program. That's why I need to know do I have to have multiple calendars or something else, and how can all be done in Java.

Comment: So to take an example, you mean, on day one, you want to import an ics file with event X and even Y, then some time later, you want to import an other ics file which would convey "delete event X, update event Y and add event Z" to the client ?

Comment: Yes, something like that. Can I have multiple different operations in a single ics file or I have to create multiple files? Or is there a way to put two streams of iCalendars in one ics file?

Comment: arnaudq, could you reply to my question if you can? It doesn't look like anyone else knows about these things.

Comment: Well I'm afraid it is not possible to get events to disappear just from using an import.

Comment: Could you explain more? You mean it is impossible to cancel or change the events that were created previously by using ics file in iCal program? So how is that being done then?

Comment: Can you answer me, so I know what to do, it is very important to me.

Comment: Sorry Gedas but I just don't see a way to do that using import. So it is hard to explain any more. I don't know in which context you are doing this but might want to instead host your file on a web server and have clients subscribe to it as a calendar subscription.

Comment: Can you at least tell me, why the importing does not work with iCal and ics files?

Comment: Can you also explain how would I go about doing web server version? What I am doing, is creating an application which can create events according to some specifications(start time, end time, number of events, event length, etc.) and before I add those events, I need to get ics file from iCal software on Mac, use it and then create a new ics which can be imported with all new events in there. I can kind of do the creation, but I am unable to perform CANCEL and UPDATE functions, I don't know the process.

Comment: Can you finish up the answer, your comments are very incomplete, just give me a final answer and I will move on.

Comment: Well sorry but the description that you gave is not clear, to me at least. As far as web subscription, you can start with http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Webcal

Comment: I explained multiple times what I am doing and what do I need. Your answer was "Sorry, it can't be done. It is hard to explain.". If you give answers here, at least make them clear or if you can't explain, why do you give answers at all. If you are having problems with English language, go to French web sites.